# how can I remove the disabled attribute for the checkbox that is selected?

Tags: jquery

I want to remove the disabled attribute only for the selected checkboxes

My code removes it from all

**Demo http://jsfiddle.net/XqUH2/8/**

```
$('input[type="number"]').change(function(){
    var priceRow = $(this).parent().next();    
    priceRow.text('$'+Math.round($(this).val()*priceRow.attr('unit-price')*100)/100);    
    updateTotal();
});

$('.ad_promote_days').prop('disabled', true);
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    if($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length == 0){
        $('.ad_promote_days').prop('disabled', true);
    }else{
        $('.ad_promote_days').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    updateTotal();    
});

function updateTotal(){
    var total = 0;    
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){            
           var priceRow = $(this).parents('tr').children('td[unit-price]');
           total += parseFloat(priceRow.text().replace('$',''));        
    });    
    $('#ad_promote_total_cost').text('$'+total);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){ 
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.ad_promote_days').prop('disabled', false);
  }
  else{ 
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.ad_promote_days').prop('disabled', true);
  }
 updateTotal();    
});
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/54rQL/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ad_promote_days').prop('disabled', true);
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){

   $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.ad_promote_days').attr('disabled', false);
    }else{
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.ad_promote_days').attr('disabled', true);
}
updateTotal();    
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XqUH2/12/)

Comment: Looks like there is a Bug in your code. Solution by RGS works as expected. Kindly correct it. Thanks,